# Google and Amazon won't work in frames?

Tags: html, frames, frameset

Am I missing something?? This code, which I think is fine, comes up with an empty page. If you change one of the URLs to facebook.com, that won't load either. Are Google, Amazon and Facebook all blocking their site from showing if it's in a frameset? (Why wouldn't they just bust out?) Or is my HTML flawed?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<FRAMESET ROWS="71, *" FRAMEBORDER=NO FRAMESPACING=0 BORDER=0>
  <FRAME SRC="http://google.com">
  <FRAME SRC="http://www.amazon.com/dp/0307951529?tag=fw-book-20" name='btm'>
</FRAMESET>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

They're blocking frames using [`x-frame-options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header). If you view their response headers you'll see this:

```
 x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

This works regardless if JavaScript is enabled. However, it does require a relatively modern browser as listed on the MDN page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, find a more elegant way to do what you're trying to accomplish without using frames. Frames are evil and have created some of the most evil webApps out there. Please refrain, and let us help you find a better way to solve what ever problem it is you're trying to solve by using frames.

I even support properly used iFrames, but not famesets...

Comment: Yeah, I don't have an easy way to do what I want. Frames are the perfect solution for helping a customer get to Amazon and complete a task-- by keeping the instructions at the top of the screen. The only reasonable alternative is to have a jump page (showing the instructions before taking the customer to Amazon), which is incredibly intrusive and a UI nightmare (what if they forget the instructions? pressing the back button will screw everything up, etc.).